# Given an object, what is the most efficient way to query hibernate for the owner of the list in which the object resides

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently I'm working on a web application where we have the following setup:
An object Project that can contain a list of 'Sub'-Project objects:

```
public class Project {
  private long id;
  private List<Project> subProjects;
  ...
  public Set<Project> getSubProjects() { return subProjects }
  public void setSubProjects(Set<Project> subProjects) { this.subProjects = subProjects }
  ...
}
```

This is stored in a PostgreSQL database using Hibernate

```
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field" default-lazy="true">
  <class name="Project" table="project">
    <id name="id" type="long">
      <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    ...
    <set cascade="all" fetch="select" name="subProjects" batch-size="10">
      <cache usage="read-write"/>
      <key column="projectIdParent"/>
      <one-to-many class="Project"/>
    </set>
    ...
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

For the sake of the question it is also relevant that a sub-project can be moved from one to another project, with every project having the same right to carry any one project as a sub-project.

*The question is this: what is the most **efficient** way to get all 'parents' of a given project.*

example:

```
public class testProject {
  ...
  Project projectA, projectB, projectC, projectD, projectE, projectF, projectG, projectH, projectI;
  projectH.getSubProjects().add(projectF);
  projectD.getSubProjects().add(projectH);
  projectD.getSubProjects().add(projectE);
  projectG.getSubProjects().add(projectD);
  projectC.getSubProjects().add(projectG);
  projectB.getSubProjects().add(projectC);
  projectA.getSubProjects().add(projectB);
  ...
  // Given projectG, get all its ancesters
}
```

Comment: I think your collection should be a Set, not a List (since it's not indexed), and the relationship from subprojects to parents should be "many-to-one". With that in mind, if you don't want to write ad-hoc recursive sql, I think you can't do better than iterating up through the project tree.

Comment: The iterating up is what we're doing right now, while this works, the amount of projects is increasing rapidly so this gets slower very quickly...

Comment: It's hard to think that this might be a problem. In that case, if you don't want to alter your datamodel, you could do a recursive query. Postgresql examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field `parents` in the `Project` class to keep track of each parents of the subproject so that you can retrieve them in constant time.

For example, when you add a subproject B to an existing project A, just add the reference to A  in B's `parents` field. Here is an example (not tested) :

```
public class Project {
    private long id;
    private List<Project> parents;
    private List<Project> subProjects;

    public void addParent(Project parent) {
        this.parents.add(parent);
    }

    public List<Project> getAllParents() {
        return parents;
    }

    public void addSubProjects(Project child) { 
        subProjects.add(child);
        child.addParent(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: We choose not to do it this way, but to use HQL to find the ancestor tree for every project. This is a whole lot faster than what we had. Your solution might even be faster, but the team decided against it because of the complexity of the application (which off course was not indicated here).